# Vue3 - script setup use 'withDefaults' for nested object,it attributes become required,how to fixed it?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I defined a props:

```js
interface Props {
  formList: BaseSearchFormListItemType[],
  inline?: boolean
  searchBtn?: {
    show?: boolean
    text?: string
    type?: string
    size?: string
  }
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  inline: true,
  searchBtn: () => ({
    show: true,
    type: 'default',
    text: '查询',
    size: 'default'
  })
})
```

`searchBtn` has four attributes not required, but when I use this child-component,

```
<BaseSearch
  :formList="searchFormList"
  :search-btn="{
  show: true
  // type: 'default',
  // text: '查询',1
  // size: 'default'
  }"
  :inline="false"/>
```

that four attributes become required,how can i fixed it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c3lb.png)

when i delete default value , it can work, but i need the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a compute prop like this:

```
const defaultSearchBtn = {
  show: true,
  type: 'default',
  text: '查询',
  size: 'default',
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  inline: true,
  searchBtn: () => ({ show: true, type: 'default', text: '查询', size: 'default' }),
})
const innerSearchBtn = computed(() => {
  return { ...defaultSearchBtn, ...props.searchBtn }
})
```